# How to print the key values which contains same values in the Hashmap in Level Order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, maps

```
Keys - Values
 1   ->  -1
 2   ->  1
 3   ->  1
 5   ->  2
 0   ->  5
 4   ->  5
```

---

the solution must contain the hash key values in level order based on same hash values

Comment: It's not really clear. What is  _level order_ here?

Comment: @COPY CAT Could you please describe in clear way what is the input and what is expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag the language, so the best I can do here is pseudo-code. The steps to produce what I *think* is the desired behavior:

1. Create an array of length equal to the `map`'s `size`
2. Add to this array pairs of items, the first the *count* inside the `map`, the second the `key`
3. Sort this list, first on the first element of the pair, then on the second as a tiebreaker
4. Print accordingly